# Graphical intuition behind an outer product

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematics, linear-algebra

One can imagine the inner product between A1 and A2 as the process of linearly mapping A2 to the one dimensional number line, using the dual vector of A1 as a map. Visually, each element in A2 is mapped to a 1D vector by the dual component in A1. And the resulting quantity must be the linear combination of all those new vectors on the 1D number line. That's why we add them all up. There is only 1 basis vector. So all that's left is the scalar quantity.

But the outer product does not follow similar logic in my mind. I don't understand how one can use a column vector to map a row vector into a matrix. What's going on graphically during this process. How can this process seem more intuitive?

Comment: This question clearly belongs to MathSE...

Comment: @JasonFunderberker I'm not sure it does. I went to my linear algebra prof. to ask about outer products and he said he didn't know and that outer products were a physics thing.

Comment: Well, the first sentence on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) seems that this language is known in linear algebra, tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help if we treat both row and column vectors as linear functions, rather than objects in their own right, so we can put them on a more equal footing. Functions can be composed in various ways.

A $1\times 3$ row vector $\vec{a}^\top$ is an $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ linear function mapping 3-vectors onto scalars (so a dual vector or 1-form).

$$\pmatrix{a_1 & a_2 & a_3}\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3}=a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3$$

A $3\times 1$ column vector $\vec{a}$ is an $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ linear function mapping scalars onto 3-vectors (so a scalar multiplication). We could imagine the vector as a velocity, tangent to the trajectory of a particle, and the scalar as time, so this function approximates the motion of a particle.

$$\pmatrix{a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3}\pmatrix{x}=\pmatrix{a_1x \\ a_2x \\ a_3x}$$

We can apply these in either order. $\vec{a}^\top\vec{b}$ is a $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ linear function mapping scalars onto scalars. It's just the function multiplying by the scalar value of the inner product.

$$\pmatrix{a_1 & a_2 & a_3}\pmatrix{b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3}\pmatrix{x}=(a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3)x=(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})x$$

$\vec{a}\vec{b}^\top$ is a $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ linear function mapping 3-vectors onto 3-vectors. We do the multiplication of a scalar by a fixed vector, but stuff a 1-form in in place of the scalar. It could therefore be thought of as constructing a vector of 1-forms, that all happen to be multiples of the same one form. Each row of the matrix is a 1-form, the collection of rows is a vector of 1-forms.

$$\pmatrix{a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3}\pmatrix{b_1 & b_2 & b_3}\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3}=\pmatrix{a_1(b_1x_1+b_2x_2+b_3x_3) \\ a_2(b_1x_1+b_2x_2+b_3x_3) \\ a_3(b_1x_1+b_2x_2+b_3x_3)}=\vec{a}(\vec{b}\cdot \vec{x})$$

This one is the outer product.

So in summary, they're made up from compositions of scalar multiplication with a constant vector $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ and the dot product with a constant vector $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. A linear function mapping $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is just a scalar, the inner product, and a linear function $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector of 1-forms or a matrix, which is the outer product.

Comment: It’s taboo to post thank you comments. But screw the norms- that was a phenomenally clear response and really helped the idea click in my head. Well done.